# How to retrieve mysql data and display it in html

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've created a database in mysql.  It works.  When a user goes to /upload.html...the user enters details:

```
first name :
last name:
email address:
```

and it gets stored in test2 database and person_list table.  I've checked and it works.

However I'm trying to display this data on /download.html

the data doesn't populate in the tables.

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

```
first name
Last name
email

first name
last name
email

first name
last name 
email and so forth...
```

I'm fairly new to php...and I know there are mistakes in this code..but can't pinpoint where..

I keep getting this:  the php code keeps displaying in the page instead of the data showing in the tables

[image]

this is download.html

```
---html code---
    <?php
    $hostdb = '************';
    $namedb = 'test2';
    $userdb = '**********';
    $passdb = '********';
    try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$*****", $userdb, $passdb);
      $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

      $sql = "SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `email` FROM `person_list` WHERE `person_list'";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if($result !== false) {
        $html_table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email Address</th></tr>';

        foreach($result as $row) {
          $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$row['firstname']. '</td><td>' .$row['lastname']. '</td><td>' .$row['email']. '</td></tr>';
        }
      }

      $conn = null;

      $html_table .= '</table>';

      echo $html_table;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>

</html>
```

Comment: It's normal to write php code blocks in html page. php generates html code. but if you want to make separate file for php code block, you can use "include" fuction <?php include "some.php"; ?>.

Comment: *"this is download.html"* - Did you instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP? If not, rename it to `.php` - Your code won't run at all if that's the case. Also, you're missing something in your `where` clause.

Comment: You should take a look at OOP, btw nice to see that u use PDO ;)

Comment: Try to eliminate ` symbols in sql query. Use ' in the code. It looks like you copied that query from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @ fred It's a php code in a html file.
I haven't included the rest of the html as it's not relevant.

Comment: You've also a quote in `person_list'` <= and as stated, something missing for it like `where column='something'`

Comment: Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Thanks I've tried the above but I keep getting errors.

Comment: I keep getting php code showing up in the page

Answer (score 3):

In the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `email` 
        FROM `person_list` 
        WHERE `person_list'";
```

You have a quote in `person_list'` <= which should be a tick `

Either replace the quote with a tick, or just remove it.

Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email 
       FROM person_list 
       WHERE person_list";
```

And add the where condition

```
WHERE person_list = value;
```

Comment: I always do without qoutes. but if u want all persons just do    $sql = "SELECT firstname,lastname,email FROM person_list"

Answer (score 1):

1st: your statement is wrong at the where statment

```
$sql = "SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `email` FROM `person_list` ;";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM person_list WHERE (column_name = 'something');";
```

2nd for seprationg:

index.php:::

```
<?php require_once("phpcode.php"); ?>
<html>......</html>
```

phpcode.php

```
<?php 
................
?>
```

3rd: displaying-

```
<html>...

<table>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>email</th>
</tr>

<?php while ($data=$results->fetch_assoc())
{

print "

 <tr>
 <td>".$data['username']."</td>
 <td>".$data['email']."</td>
 </tr>

";
?>

</table>
....</html>
```

Comment: how do you access your php file??? as file:\\c:\...... ???? or through a server? you need a server to run php code, you also need to configure it to run the php.. appserv will do all that for you  http://www.appservnetwork.com/      if you have a server and it runs PHP then check the opening and closing tags, must start <?php and end with ?>

Comment: I use linux.  Data input works.  Data output doesn't.

Comment: do you have an apache server installed? also, how do you access the file for viewing? what is the url displayed when you view the page?

Comment: Yes I do.  I have everything installed.  I use linux command line.

Comment: you are losing me,,, you aren't making any sense.. how are you opening the php file? (not edit but view) if you are opening it through the server i.e. http://localhost/thewebpage and the php code shows then you need to go to the httpd.conf file for apache server and add the CGI extension of php there, check  http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml ,focus on step 4 and beyond